# Tkinter Color Tile Matching Game Button Errors

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a color matching game in python tkinter. I will eventually have it so that it can have different sizes but am currently working on making the matching work. I currently have it so that the colors are not shuffled so it is easier to test. However my current problem is when picking two tiles that don't match those tiles lock up and aren't able to be used again. They don't give any information about clicking them and there are no errors.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

#video with simple version of code
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlMPVGSEEDw


#size of board
size = [4]
length = random.choice(size)
game = True
#all the color options
colors =['snow','snow', 'peach puff', 'peach puff', 'azure', 'azure', 'navy', 'navy',
    'cyan', 'cyan', 'lawn green', 'lawn green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'dark goldenrod', 'dark goldenrod',
    'salmon', 'salmon', 'purple', 'purple', 'gold', 'gold', 'red', 'red',
    'hot pink', 'hot pink', 'dark slate gray', 'dark slate gray', 'rosy brown', 'rosy brown',
     'aquamarine', 'aquamarine',]

count = 0
answer_list = []
answer_key = []
newcolors = colors[0:16]
#random.shuffle(newcolors)

#Check to see if match
def update(x,y,length):
    global count, answer_list, answer_key
    #collect the two tiles
    if board[x][y]["bg"] == "white" and count < 2:
        number = x * length + y
        print(number)
        board[x][y]["bg"] = newcolors[number]
        answer_list.append(newcolors[number])
        answer_key.append(number)
        print(answer_list)
        
        
        #Check to see if match
    if len(answer_list) == 2:
        if answer_list[0] == answer_list[1]:
            print("match")
            board[x][y]["state"] = DISABLED
            y = int(answer_key[0] % length)
            x = int((answer_key[0] - y) / length)            
            board[x][y]["state"] = DISABLED
            count = 0
            answer_list = []
            answer_key = []
        else:
            print("Those do not match")
            count = 0
            answer_list = []
            
            board[x][y]["bg"] = "White"
            y = int(answer_key[0] % length)
            x = int((answer_key[0] - y) / length)            
            board[x][y]["bg"] = "White"
            answer_key = []
    

#y = number % length
#x = (number - y)/length
board = [[Button(root,bg = "white", text = " ",height=3, width=4, command = (lambda x = x, y = y: update(x,y,length))) for y in range(length)] for x in range(length)]

for x in range(length):
    for y in range(length):
        board[x][y].grid(row=x,column=y)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You consider a button to be a valid choice if its background is `"white"`, which is the initial state of the buttons. But when there's a mismatch, you set the backgrounds of the chosen buttons to `"White"` instead.